# Approximation of a function

Tags: approximation

Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a function of $x$, with a parameter $\theta > 0$, such that

- $f$ is continuous
- $f$ is strictly decreasing
- $f(0) = \infty$
- $f(1) = 0$

For example, $f(x) = (- \log(x))^{\theta - 1}$.

For a given $\theta$, is there a way to approximate
$f^{-1}(2 f(0.5))$ for any such $f$?

Comment: With just the given information, I'd say **no**. For any given $x \in (0,0.5)$, there exists a function that satisfies your four bullet points and such that $f^{-1}(2f(0.5)) = x$. Furthermore, I don't really see how $\theta$ is intended to come in to the problem: is there some further dependence on $\theta$ that you forgot to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value could be almost anything. Take for $\theta > 0$:
$$
f_\theta(x) = x^{- \theta} - 1
$$
Then $f_\theta(1/2) = 2^\theta - 1$, and $$f^{-1}_\theta(2 f_\theta(1/2)) = \left( 2(2^\theta - 1) + 1 \right)^{1/\theta} = (2^{\theta + 1} - 1)^{1/\theta} \approx 2^{(\theta + 1)/\theta} \left(1 - \frac{2^{- \theta - 1}}{\theta} + \ldots\right)$$ by using the first two terms of the binomial expansion.

As $f_\theta(0) \to \infty$ and $f_\theta(1) = 0$, one could also scale this function at will, and mangle it in a myriard other ways.

Comment: Thanks! can you explain the approximation please?

Comment: @user7064, $2(2^r - 1) \approx 2^{r + 1}$ if $r >> 0$, unless $\theta$ is very small, $2^{r + 1} \theta$ is much larger than 1. **Very** crude, but gives an idea how it behaves. Looking it over, should have just used $\theta$ instead of $r$, and chucked the factor. I.e., just have done $f_\theta(x) = x^{- \theta} - 1$. Oh, well.